# Loading online xml data to slider in R shiny dashboard

Tags: r, xml, shiny, rcurl, xml2

My friend and I built an R shiny dashboard using downloaded data. The code is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape)
library(scales)



ecd <- read.csv("ecd-figures.csv")

c(
  "No of case" = "no_of_case",
  "Minor Case" = "minor_case",
  "All Non Fatal Case" = "all_non_fatal_case",
  "Fatal Case" = "fatal_case"
) -> vec

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel
  (
    checkboxGroupInput("feature",
                       "Feature",
                       vec),
    sliderInput(
      "year",
      "Year",
      min = min(ecd$year),
      max = max(ecd$year),
      value = range(ecd$year),
      sep = "",
      step = 1
    )
  ),
  
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("correlation_plot")),
    tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("ecd"))
  ))
))



server <- function(input, output) {
  yearrange <- reactive({
    ecd %>%
      subset(year %in% input$year[1]:input$year[2]) %>%
      select(c(year, input$feature))
  })
  
  
  
  output$correlation_plot <- renderPlot({
    ecdsubset <- yearrange()
    
    ecdsubset <- melt(ecdsubset, id = "year")
    validate(need(input$feature, 'Check at least one item.'))
    ggplot(ecdsubset, aes(x = year, y = value, color = variable)) + geom_line(size = 1) + scale_x_continuous(breaks =
                                                                                                               seq(input$year[1], input$year[2], by = 1))
    
  })
  output$ecd <- renderTable({
    yearrange()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The simple data file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pZQe89wxw14lirW2mRIgi9h29yPyc7Fs/view?usp=sharing

Then, I want to make everything online, i.e. calling api and not to download the csv file. It seems ok to read the contents rather simply, as follows:

```
library(xml2)

ecd_xml <-"https://www.labour.gov.hk/datagovhk/resource/ecd/ecd-figures.xml"
read_ecd <- read_xml(ecd_xml)
xml_find_all(read_ecd, ".//year")

{xml_nodeset (5)}
[1] <year>2015</year>
[2] <year>2016</year>
[3] <year>2017</year>
[4] <year>2018</year>
[5] <year>2019</year>
```

The problem is: how to parse every piece of information from the xml contents onto the dashboard?

Take the slidebar as an example. How to display the slidebar labels (i.e. 2015 and 2019) from parsing the `<year>` tag and selecting the max and min values?

And, can you recommend some reading materials for me to learn the whole process from xml to dashboard? Many many thanks in advance.

(P.S. I've tried to use `xml` package instead, since there are some standard arguments to find the max, min, and avg values of attributes. But I ran into another big error -

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

What should I do? My R version is 4.0.5 (2021-03-31).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xml2::as_list` to create a tibble from the XML tree.
Moreover, you can use `shiny::updateSliderInput` to update UI slider ranges:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape)
library(scales)
library(xml2)

vec <- c(
  "No of case" = "no_of_case",
  "Minor Case" = "minor_case",
  "All Non Fatal Case" = "all_non_fatal_case",
  "Fatal Case" = "fatal_case"
)

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxGroupInput(
      "feature",
      "Feature",
      vec
    ),
    sliderInput(
      "year",
      "Year",
      min = 2000,
      max = 2001,
      value = c(2000, 2001),
      sep = "",
      step = 1
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("correlation_plot")),
    tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
  ))
))



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  xml <-
    "https://www.labour.gov.hk/datagovhk/resource/ecd/ecd-figures.xml" %>%
    read_xml()
  
  table <-
    xml %>%
    xml_find_all(".//item") %>%
    map(as_list) %>%
    map(~ .x %>% as_tibble()) %>%
    bind_rows() %>%
    unnest(everything()) %>%
    type_convert()
  
  years <- table$year %>% unique()
  
  updateSliderInput(
    session = session,
    inputId = "year",
    min = min(years),
    max = max(years),
    value = c(min(years), max(years)) # current selected range
  )
  
  sub_table <- reactive({
    table %>%
      filter(year %in% input$year[1]:input$year[2]) %>%
      select(c(year, input$feature))
  })
  
  
  output$correlation_plot <- renderPlot({
    validate(need(input$feature, "Check at least one item."))
    
    sub_table() %>%
      pivot_longer(-year) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, color = name)) +
      geom_line(size = 1) +
      scale_x_continuous(
        breaks = seq(input$year[1], input$year[2], by = 1)
      )
  })
  output$table <- renderTable({
    sub_table()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Let me try. Should I change all ````ecd```` label into  ````xml_years````, such as ````tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("ecd"))```` --> ````tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("xml_years"))```` and
 ````yearrange <- reactive({
    ecd %>%```` into ````yearrange <- reactive({ xml_years %>% ```` ?

Comment: No. The first argument of any function ending with `Output` is the `outputId` which must not linked to an object of type different from `character` (here: numeric vector). I prefixed it with `xml_` to not confuse it with `yearrange`. I suggest to rename `xml_years` to `ecd_years` and to rename `yearrange` to `ecd_subset`. Then you do not need the duplicate  `ecdsubset` anymore.

Comment: I see. But if I want to stop relying on ecd (that is the csv) anymore, it seems that all the ecd$ and ecd%>% should be replaced....

Comment: @ronzenith I revised my answer to make it in depended on the csv file

Comment: Thanks @danlooo. I tried but there is a problem in rendering plot. When I want to have more than one line in the same plot, R fails and prompt a warning ````Warning: Error in match.names: names do not match previous names [No stack trace available]````. 

Online QAs usually regards it as an error in binding rows, but R works in rendering tables with multiple columns i.e. multiple features. Do you know the reasons? Anything wrong with this line of code ```` df <- melt(sub_table(), id = "year")```` ?

Comment: @ronzenith I revised my answer. Switching from `melt` to `pivot_longer` solved the problem.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. It seems just a small mistake in binding data. The correct way is change to long form, right?

Comment: Yes. `ggplot` maps one column to one aesthetic like x, y, color etc. You want to color by variable name. Variable names are in multiple columns of `sub_table` so you have to go from wide to long format. Then we've got a column named `name` which we can map to color.